# Symbology remains empty/invisible in legend and map after importing shapefile into QGIS 3.22 Białowieża

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, symbology

**The problem:**

When I import a shapefile into QGIS 3.22 Białowieża, there is no symbology showing in the legend and the items are invisible in the map.

The shapefile has a symbology in it's properties, but it doesn't show in the layers panel:

[image]

When I select the features in the attribute table, the feature is showing up selected in the map at the correct location. [image]

I found that when I copy the styling of another shapefile and paste it into the empty one, the shapefile symbology is updated and I can suddenly see all features correctly in the legend and map. So, this is a work around the problem but not a long lasting fix because it's quite anoying.

**What I tried so far:**

- Yesterday I imported a shapefile with a different CRS (25831) into QGIS and after I restarted the program the next day this problem arose. Therefore at first I thought it was a problem with the right CRS, but the project CRS (28992) and CRS of the shapefiles I try to import today (28992) are correct and as I stated above, when the features are selected they show up at the correct position. I already played around with the settings in the CRS menu. I also checked the .prj files;
  [image]
- I set the default styles in the properties menu, but this didn't help;
  [image]

Does any of you know the answer to this problem?

Hope to hear from you!

Comment: As I can see, your "Test" layer has no symbology. Just give it a symbol, and it should be ok! In the layer properties, not in the projet.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

That unfortunately, doesn't work. The shapefile already has a symbology in the properties, but it remains invisible.

Maybe I should add that to my question ;)

Comment: Alright, for some reason QGIS suddenly imports all shapefiles with an opacity of 0%.......... That's the whole issue..

Comment: Yes, because as you can see in the properties of Qgis, you set the default opacity to 0%

Comment: QGIS did this on it's own :) I only started playing around with the 'default symbols' menu after it didn't show the symbology. Before the problem arose, I had never seen the 'default symbols' menu and the defaults symbols were all empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but QGIS managed to change a setting on it's own. A setting which I had never seen in my life..

Project -> Properties -> Default Styles -> Here you can change the default symbology of shapefiles when imported into QGIS. So this setting randomly had an opacity of 0%, so all shapefiles (no matter the geometry) that were imported were invisible.

So the shapefiles already had a symbology, but were invisible.